# Как изменить число с буквой e на обычный формат отображения чисел?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть число `9.4e-7`  -
как его изменить на человеческий вид используя javascript или может уже есть встроенный тип на html/css?

Comment: Вам нужно, чтоб получилось 9.47 или 9.4-7?

Comment: думаю, нужно 0.000000094

Comment: (9.4e-7).toFixed(8) 8 = степень+кол-во цифр после запятой. А что делать с 9.4e+37 - не знаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привет, есть такой метод: [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
(1.23e+20).toFixed(2); // Returns '123000000000000000000.00'
```

Но у этого метода есть ограничение - число должно быть меньше 1e21.
Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript) несколько готовых вариантов для полного диапозона.
Вот [еще](https://gist.github.com/jiggzson/b5f489af9ad931e3d186). Погуглите на английском)